# How to display tombstone messages(with null values) in Opensearch via Opensearch Kafka Connector?

Tags: apache-kafka, opensearch

I have a task to display Kafka topic messages in Opensearch via Opensearch Kafka Connector, including tombstone messages (with null values).

Example of messages:

```
text1    {"key1":"val1"}
text2    null
text3    null
text4    {"key2":"val2"}
```

Configuration of Opensearch Connector:

```
{
    "name": "opensearch-sink-rtf",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.aiven.kafka.connect.opensearch.OpensearchSinkConnector",
        "topics.regex": "^rtf.*",
        "connection.url": "https://1.1.1.1:9210/,https://2.2.2.2:9210/,https://3.3.3.3:9210/",
        "connection.username": "kafka-connector",
        "connection.password": "************",
        "compact.map.entries": "true",
        "schema.ignore": "true",
        "key.ignore": "false",
        "behavior.on.malformed.documents": "ignore",
        "flush.timeout.ms" : "180000",
        "type.name": "kafka-connect",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false"
    }
}
```

Options `behavior.on.null.values` has a default value `ignore`.

I also tried to use these options:

```
"drop.invalid.message": true,
"behavior.on.null.values": "ignore",
```

But it doesn't work. Opensearch creates indexes only if the message values are not null. Is there some way to display messages with empty values?